# Is there anyway an app can use more than 16mb in memory?

Tags: android, memory, memory-management

I understand most Android devices have a 16mb limit (24mb on Nexus One) on the Java heap size.  Is there any way a single app can use more memory than that?  I know the native SDK doesn't have this limitation but I'd like to stick with Java.

Comment: Would splitting the app into multiple processes help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No you cannot use more memory.

Comment: You can allocate as much as you want from native code yes. It's not recommended though, you should play nice with other apps.